# Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. [so frustrating]

Tags: flash, null, actionscript, adobe

please help me, I'm really noob at this.

I just can't find what's wrong. Everything works fine in frame 1 but when I clicked the *next* button the error appears. I've checked the instance name of all the buttons I've used and everything is instantiated.I just don't really know what else should I change. The pauseMusic2 button is already existing. I'm also wondering why the nextFrame (); doesn't work in line 54 in frame1.

**THE ERROR**

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at RECOVER_AGUILAREXERCISE_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()[RECOVER_AGUILAREXERCISE_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:21]
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at RECOVER_AGUILAREXERCISE_fla::MainTimeline/nextSoundTrack01()[RECOVER_AGUILAREXERCISE_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:54]
```

**CODE in frame 2**

```
stop();
 album01.gotoAndPlay(49);
 title2.play();
 import flash.media.SoundMixer;
 import flash.media.Sound;

 var sound02:Sound = new SITNight();
 var soundChannel02:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel
 var soundLastPosition02: Number = 0;


 soundChannel02 = sound02.play(0);


 pauseMusic2.pauseBTN.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseSoundTrack02);

 function pauseSoundTrack02 (e:MouseEvent): void {
 pauseMusic2.visible = false;
 soundLastPosition02 = soundChannel02.position;
 soundChannel02.stop();
 }



 playMusic2.playBTN.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playSoundTrack02);

 function playSoundTrack02 (e:MouseEvent): void {
 pauseMusic2.visible = true;
 soundChannel02 = sound02.play(soundLastPosition02);
 }


 stopMusic2.stopBTN.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSoundTrack02);

 function stopSoundTrack02 (e:MouseEvent): void {
 pauseMusic2.visible = false;
 soundChannel02.stop();
 soundLastPosition02 = 0;
 }

 nextMusic2.nextBTN.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, nextSoundTrack02)

 function nextSoundTrack02 (e:MouseEvent): void {
 pauseMusic2.visible = true;
 soundChannel02.stop();
 soundLastPosition02 = 0;
 nextFrame();
 }

 prevMusic2.prevBTN.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, prevSoundTrack02)

 function prevSoundTrack02 (e:MouseEvent): void {
 pauseMusic2.visible = true;
 soundChannel02.stop();
 soundLastPosition02 = 0;
 gotoAndStop(1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you identify which line is line 21 in frame2? 
From what I see, I think the issue is with "soundChannel02" not being initialized.

Probably because of missing "()" in `var soundChannel02:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel` if not typo.